# 'wget' full web site based on frames

Tags: linux, wget

I have a little problem. I want recursively download [that web page](http://base.safework.ru/iloenc), but it based on "frames". Standard methods can't help me. I try different variants, but nothing. Maximum I can download one recursion, I found example [there](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/html/wget/wget_2.html). How can I grab that web site fully, and than use it offline? Thx.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for mirroring applications? For Windows I know WinHTTrack and Teleport Pro; I'm sure there are some alternatives for other OSes.

Comment: I think, I will try them after fail with that. I wanna do it from linux and command 'wget'.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a local copy of a site use **--mirror**:

```
wget --mirror http://www.example.com/
```

Some of the other options are useful too:

**--convert-links** converts absolute links to local links, so you can browse the site locally.

**--HTML-extension** adds .html to any resources that do not have a suffix (this is useful for browsing otherwise very dynamic sites locally via apache)

**-p** gets images, css and all resources required for the page to load

So:

```
wget --mirror --convert-links --HTML-extension -p http://www.example.com/
```

Finally, if it's not your site, then be polite and add a **-w** (wait between requests, in seconds)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to use that command. Try to parse http://base.safework.ru/iloenc . That site is based on frames, and I can't do it with default methods((( Like that, I will get only first page frame and will getting it infinity, but not other pages and frames.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 wget -E -H -k -K -p "http://yoursite.com/path"
```

Works for my use case (to download referenced frame HTMLs)

Comment: could you explain those command line options, or at least link to a reference?

Comment: a link to the full, detailed reference for every single flag: `wget --help`

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the commands? Are you on MSWindows? E.g. "wget --mirror –w 2 –p --HTML-extension –-convert-links –P c:\wget_files\example1 http://base.safework.ru/iloenc"

Comment: I use linux and it's native command wget. I try to do in that way, but it recursively parse itself (frame, than frame in frame, and frame in frame.... and infinity. All frames are from first page, not from other pages).